# Inkscape: How to set a stroke/object/path at 0 degrees, i.e. perfectly horizontal?

Tags: inkscape, stroke, rotate

I created a simple stroke line and it looks tilted, i.e. there's an angle with the horizontal. I would like this angle to be 0 degrees so the stroke is perfectly horizontal.

I was wondering if someone could tell me how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the first location for your line, then press and hold control key.

This will restrict the line to angles of 15° and snap to the nearest multiple. It's easy to restrict to 0° in this manner.